# Enforcing conditions on truncated exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, truncated-distributions

The CDF for an exponential distribution of rate $\lambda$ truncated at T is

$F(t) = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda t}}{1-e^{-\lambda T}}$. (for $t<T$, else 0).

I would like to determine $\lambda$ and $T$ such that F(5) = 0.95, and F(2) = 0.8. (So 80% of events happen within time 2, and 95% of events happen within time 5). However, it would seem these equations have no solution. Is this actually true? I'm struggling to see why I can't find a truncated exponential satisfying these conditions? Have I made a mistake somewhere?

I entered the equations in Mathematica to find that there wasn't a solution. But similarly,

\begin{gather}
F(5) = \frac{1-e^{-5\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda T}} \\
F(2) = \frac{1-e^{-2\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda T}}. \\
\end{gather}

Calculating the ratio of these, I get \begin{equation}
\frac{F(5)}{F(2)} = \frac{1-e^{-5\lambda}}{1-e^{-2\lambda}} = \frac{19}{16} \end{equation}.

This can be solved for $\lambda$ which gives $\lambda \approx 0.89316$.
Putting this back into the expression for $F(5)$, we end up wanting to solve

\begin{equation} F(5) = \frac{1-e^{-5\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda T}} \approx \frac{0.9885}{1-e^{-\lambda T}}. \end{equation}

However, the numerator is already greater than the value I want it to be, so there's now way that this equation can equal 0.95. Is my thinking flawed here? Are there some other roots that I am somehow missing? Or are the numerical errors caused by putting in rounded values (to 4-5dp) the cause of this?

Comment: The equations usually do have a solution.  You will find them easier to solve by writing $\eta_i=1-F(t_i)(1-\exp(-\lambda T)),$ which leads to the system of linear equations $\lambda t_i=\eta_i.$ Solve that for $\lambda$ and then solve the original equations for $T.$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Apologies. I have added some more detail. For what it's worth, this isn't a homework question. It's a problem I came across trying to do something else. But I appreciate it does seem that way.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I'm a little confused as to how you get that. Don't we have $\eta_i = e^{-\lambda t_i}$? Would this get me a different answer to the inconsistent one I included in my edited post?

Comment: At the end of your post you have an equation that is easily solved for $\lambda T.$ Divide that solution by $\lambda$ to obtain $T.$

Comment: @whuber But that equation doesn't have a solution. You get $\frac{19}{20} = \frac{0.9885}{1-e^{-\lambda T}}$. This becomes the equation $e^{-\lambda T} = -0.04052$ which has no (real) solution (assuming $T>5, \lambda > 0$).

Comment: When it has no solution, that proves your initial conditions are impossible.  A better test of any solution method is to begin with an actual distribution -- that is, a valid pair $(\lambda, T)$ -- and compute two pairs $(x,F(x)).$ Then work backwards to check that you recover $(\lambda,T)$ from that information.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It works if I choose values (and I can recover them using this method). I'm just surprised that there aren't values that satisfy these conditions!

Comment: You don't need the full power of Mathematica for this: WolframAlpha can also tell you. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%281-Exp%28-%CE%BB+5%29%29%2F%281-Exp%28-%CE%BB+T%29%29%3D0.95%2C+%281-Exp%28-%CE%BB+2%29%29%2F%281-Exp%28-%CE%BB+T%29%29%3D0.8%2C+T+%3E+0